# Permutaciones con Python: Número de palabras de 5 letras que contienen la letra N:

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Queremos calcular cuántas palabras de 5 letras, que contengan la letra 'N', se pueden formar con las letras de la palabra "EQUATIONS". Para ello razonamos lo siguiente.

- La letra "N" puede ir en cualquiera de las cinco posiciones de la palabra de 5 letras.
- Una vez que elegimos la posición para la letra "N", nos quedan 8 letras para llenar las otras cuatro posiciones (ya que ya hemos utilizado una "N").
- Para las otras posiciones, podemos elegir entre las 8 letras restantes.
- Esto nos da un total de 5 × 8 × 7 × 6 × 5 = 8400 palabras posibles.

Por lo tanto, se pueden formar 8400 palabras de 5 letras con la palabra "EQUATIONS" que contienen la letra "N".

Escribo el código siguiente para realizar el cálculo con Python.

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

word = "EQUATIONS"
letter = 'N'

# Obtener todas las permutaciones posibles de 5 letras
permutations = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.permutations(word, 5)))

# Filtrar las permutaciones según la condición de contener la letra "N"
filtered_permutations = permutations[permutations.apply(lambda x: letter in x, axis=1)]

# Calcular el número de palabras que cumplen con la condición
count = len(filtered_permutations)

print("Número de palabras de 5 letras que contienen la letra", letter + ":", count)
```

En él, **itertools.permutations** genera todas las permutaciones posibles de 5 letras a partir de la palabra word y devuelve una lista de permutaciones que convertimos en DataFrame.
Para filtrar las permutaciones según la condición de que contengan la letra "N", hacemos:
**filtered_permutations = permutations[permutations.apply(lambda x: letter in x, axis=1)]**.
Aplicamos una función 'lambda' a cada fila del DataFrame 'permutations' utilizando **permutations.apply(lambda x: letter in x, axis=1)**. Esta función lambda verifica si la letra 'letter' está presente en cada permutación, representada por la variable x y devuelve una serie booleana que indica si la permutación contiene la letra 'letter' o no.

La serie booleana filtra las filas que cumplen con la condición (es decir, contienen la letra 'N') y se almacenan en el DataFrame filtered_permutations.

Sin embargo, devuelve **'Número de palabras de 5 letras que contienen la letra N: 0'**, lo cual no es correcto.

¿Cuál es mi error?. ¿Hy otra manera de calcular permutaciones con pandas?. Agradeceré ayuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

Si imprimes la información del `dataframe` justo después de crearlo, utilizando `print(permutations.info)` puedes ver lo siguiente:

```
       0  1  2  3  4
0      E  Q  U  A  T
1      E  Q  U  A  I
2      E  Q  U  A  O
3      E  Q  U  A  N
4      E  Q  U  A  S
...   .. .. .. .. ..
15115  S  N  O  I  E
15116  S  N  O  I  Q
15117  S  N  O  I  U
15118  S  N  O  I  A
15119  S  N  O  I  T
```

Tienes un `dataframe` de 5 columnas y cada columna tiene una letra, por lo que la función que tienes en `lambda` no debería ser `lambda x: letter in x` sino `lambda x: (x == letter).any()` ya que lo que te interesa es ver si cualquier letra de cualquier columna en cada fila es igual a `letter` y para eso sirve el `any()`.

Si desearas segmentar el `dataframe` y quedarte únicamente con los que tienen la letra "N" en cualquier columna, lo recomendable sería utilizar `loc` ya que si en algún momento intentas asignar nuevos valores a tu segmento podrías incurrir en alertas del tipo [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

word = "EQUATIONS"
letter = 'N'

# Obtener todas las permutaciones posibles de 5 letras
permutations = pd.DataFrame(list(itertools.permutations(word, 5)))

# Filtrar las permutaciones según la condición de contener la letra "N"
filtered_permutations = permutations.loc[permutations.apply(lambda x: (x == letter).any(), axis=1)]

# Calcular el número de palabras que cumplen con la condición
count = len(filtered_permutations)

print("Número de palabras de 5 letras que contienen la letra", letter + ":", count)
```

Pero yo lo haría de una forma un poco diferente, yo crearía el `dataframe` con una sola columna que contenga la palabra:

```
permutations = pd.DataFrame({'Palabra': [''.join(p) for p in list(itertools.permutations(word, 5))]})
```

Que al usar `print(permutations.info)` devuelve lo siguiente:

```
        Palabra
0       EQUAT
1       EQUAI
2       EQUAO
3       EQUAN
4       EQUAS
...       ...
15115   SNOIE
15116   SNOIQ
15117   SNOIU
15118   SNOIA
15119   SNOIT
```

Luego buscamos si el `string` contiene el caracter `letter`

```
permutations['Palabra'].str.contains(letter)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

word = "EQUATIONS"
letter = 'N'

# Obtener todas las permutaciones posibles de 5 letras
permutations = pd.DataFrame({'Palabra': [''.join(p) for p in list(itertools.permutations(word, 5))]})

# Filtrar las permutaciones según la condición de contener la letra "N"
filtered_permutations = permutations.loc[permutations['Palabra'].str.contains(letter)]

# Calcular el número de palabras que cumplen con la condición
count = len(filtered_permutations)

print("Número de palabras de 5 letras que contienen la letra", letter + ":", count)
```

En ambos casos el resultado imprime:

```
Número de palabras de 5 letras que contienen la letra N: 8400
```

Comment: Gracias. AHora lo entiendo. La función lambda lambda x: (x == letter).any() se define para cada fila x del DataFrame. Dentro de esta función lambda, se verifica si la letra letter se encuentra en la fila x. La expresión (x == letter) devuelve una serie de booleanos indicando si cada elemento de la fila es igual a la letra letter. Luego, se utiliza el método any() para verificar si hay al menos un valor verdadero en la serie de booleanos. Esto devuelve un solo valor booleano para cada fila.